# How to get an input from the user with a loop to get a number between 2 and 10 not a string?

Tags: java, eclipse

I get stuck in this while loop. 
It's about get an input (int) n = number so we need hasNextInt() and also this input needs to be between 2 and 10.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //kb = keyboard
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean out = true;
        //n = number
        int n = 0;

        //loop
        while (out) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 2 and 10.");

            if (kb.hasNextInt()) {
                n = kb.nextInt();
                if ((n >= 2 && n <= 10)) {
                    out = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please a number between 2 and 10.");
                    kb.next();
                }
                out = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Enter a number!");
                kb.next();
            }
        }
        out = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Scanner#nextLine()` and then convert the `String` to an `int` with the help of [`Integer.parseInt(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-)

Comment: did you forget `break`?

Comment: You seem to have n and salir not being defined?

Comment: Yes sorry already changed! salir =  out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
Integer temp = null;

while (temp == null) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 2 and 10.");
    final String input = kb.nextLine();
    try {
        final Integer value = Integer.valueOf(input);
        if (value >= 2 && value < 10) {
            temp = value;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Bad number, try again");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println("Not a number, try again");
    }
}
int n = temp;
```

This is similar to @Antoniossss answer, but it handles a few edge cases (non numeric input). It uses a temp value to hold the result, and an Integer called value to hold the value while  it is validated.

Comment: That looks like a typo on your part, `Intenger` != `Integer`

Comment: last thing on `if (value >= 2 && value < 10)` says _The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) Integer, int_ @jrtapsell

Comment: What version of Java are you running?

Comment: I'm running _jdk-8u144-windows-x64_ @jrtapsell on _eclipse ide_

Comment: Autoboxing should allow those, could you check you aren't seeing the target version to an old version

Comment: It was that!! It was set on 1.4 insted of 1.7.... Thanks a lot! Now it works perfectly @jrtapsell

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler

```
public static void main (String[]args){
        //kb = keyboard
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 0;
        //loop
        do{
            System.out.println("Enter a number between 2 and 10.");
            n=kb.nextInt();
        }while(n<2 || n>10);
        System.out.println("Nice, you selected "+n);
    }
```

Comment: This program will crash if your input is a string  :-) may be type checking is missed

Comment: How does this handle the case of the user entering an arbitrary text string?  I would expect you'd either want to manually check `hasNextInt()`, or catch the resulting `InputMismatchException` if, for example, the input is "0xfoo12".

Comment: wrap `nextInt` with try-catch and ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I tried also this one.

```
    do {
        System.out.print("Choose a number between[2-10]");

        while(!kb.hasNextInt()){
            kb.nextLine();
            System.out.println("It's not a valid number.");             
        }
        n = kb.nextInt();
    } while ((v<=1 || v>=11));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the redundant code, and using a Do-while loop to test after the body and having a control like

```
do
{
     if(n>=2&&n<=10)
     {
     ...
     out = true;
     }
     else
     }
     out = false;
     ...
     }
}
while(!out);
```

That should work better to test it.